# How to deploy simple SignalR in IIS?

Tags: iis, signalr, web-deployment

I followed this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr). It worked great in Visual-Studio-2017. I am utterly new to web and signalR (and stackoverflow) and cannot figure out how to deploy it in IIS.

When I launch the index.html file from my ..\SignalRChat\SignalRChat\ folder, I get this mysterious error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.html:34)
    at c (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21)
    at HTMLDocument.q (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21)
```

BTW: Although I have found other similar questions, none of them have helped!

Answer (score 0):

After much hunting and pecking, we abandoned the MS example mentioned above. Instead we used the code in https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5162436/Simple-SignalR-Server-and-Client-Applications-Demo which uses a self-hosted' option for SignalR. (A well-written article that contains three projects: JavascriptClient, WinFormsClient, and WinFormsServer.)

Using **example.com** as the domain name and x:\example\ as the folder in which the site is hosted by a VPS provider like AWS or Azure, here's what we did.

1. Created two folders: x:\example\chat\ and x:\example\msg\ in the file system
2. Created two subdomain websites chat.example.com and msg.example.com in IIS
3. In the domain hosting service, made adjustments so that both would be "visible" (it took about 36 hours before we could reach them via browsers from some of our desktops)
4. Installed the JavascriptClient files (which has an index.htm file) in x:\example\chat\
5. Created the x:\example\WinFormsServer folder and installed its files in it
6. In IIS made sure chat.example.com is STARTED
7. In IIS made sure msg.example.com is STOPPED

Once all of these sites were 'visible'

- On the VPS's virtual Windows server launched the WinFormServer.exe, set its URL to http://msg.example.com, and hit [Start] the server
- On my local Windows desktop, launched the WinFormsClient.exe, set its URL to http://msg.example.com/signalr and tapped [Connect] to the SignalR Server
- On another local Windows desktop, launched a browser and went go to http://chat.foo.com and when the form appeared set its URL to http://msg.example.com/signalr and tapped [Connect] to the SignalR Server.

Now the WinForms client and Javascript (aka web) client can happily chat! And SignalR will not interfere with the pages on the the main site, namely, http://example.com.